Is it possible to dynamically change the contents of an html file in nodejs?
The front-end is being developed with React, and the back-end is being developed with NestJS. An email will be sent to the user for notification in certain situations by back-end. My project has storage for HTML with mail templates, and NestJS accesses this and retrieves the HTML.
The problem is that the contents of the email must be dynamically changed in the backend.
ex) Q&A, Membership registration approval
There are two things I thought about.

A separate server receives the API from the back-end, dynamically configures HTML, and returns it.
After receiving the HTML from the backend, access the className directly, set the value, and send the email to the mail server.

I'm planning to proceed with 2, but I'm curious whether this method is commonly used and whether I can access the element directly from the HTML file received from the server. This is because it is not a web browser, so access through the document is unlikely to be possible.
Other than this, is there a way to receive an html file directly from nodejs and dynamically modify the contents?

Generally what you're talking about is handled by some sort of template mechanism.

I'm trying to parse html and set values ​​through a library called cheerio.

That's probably the wrong way to do things, but I don't know anything about "cheerio". A template mechanism allows you to create a basic template for some sort of content, like HTML, and includes facilities for binding values into the result and (usually) some basic logic like conditionals and iteration.

You say "My project has storage for HTML with mail templates", does that mean you already have a templating mechanism in there?

for HTML manipulations you could try JSDOM npm package

I think you can do it like that
const template = handlebars.compile(fs.readFileSync(templatePath, 'utf8'));
const html = template(data);

